# Facebook ShareDialog: back button doesn't catch by Activity

Tags: android, facebook, dialog, facebook-android-sdk

I follow tutorial for write ShareDialog of facebook api, but it doesn't work. When activity is launched, after setting up environment, i show automatically ShareDialog. If i press back button when that dialog is showed, my app close dialog, and open it again. It seems that back button isn't catch by activity. This is my code:

```
public class ShareScoreOnFb extends FragmentActivity {
private static UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private static Activity activity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_score_on_fb);
    activity = this;
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, null);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
            new FacebookDialog.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                    String gesture = FacebookDialog
                            .getNativeDialogCompletionGesture(data);
                    if (gesture != null) {
                        if ("post".equals(gesture)) {
                            Toast.makeText(ShareScoreOnFb.this,
                                    "success",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        ShareScoreOnFb.this.finish();
                    }
                    ShareScoreOnFb.this.finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(PendingCall pendingCall,
                        Exception error, Bundle data) {

                    Toast.makeText(ShareScoreOnFb.this, error.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ShareScoreOnFb.this.finish();
                }

            });

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    share();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i("TAG", "backpressed");
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

private void share() {
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    int myScore = intent.getIntExtra("MYSCORE", -1);
    int oppScore = intent.getIntExtra("OPPONENT_SCORE", -1);
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setName("Score").setLink("http://www.google.it")
            .setDescription(myScore + " " + oppScore)
            .setPicture("http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~junggon/tools/gear.png")
            .build();

    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

}
```

}

I can't find any solution, and i'm going to be crazy!

Answer (score 0):

When you call the native share dialog (in FacebookDialog), it will start another activity (call it Activity Foo) in the Facebook app. So if you click on the back button, it's Activity Foo that catches the back button, and finishes Activity Foo. I believe here's the sequence of events:

- Your ShareScoreOnFb activity calls shareDialog.present()
- Activity Foo starts, and shows the share dialog
- You click back
- Activity Foo finishes, and calls your callback (in onActivityResult)
- once onActivityResult completes, your ShareScoreOnFb activity's onResume is called, and it will try to share() again

Comment: ok, but how i can avoid this behavior? when i call backpressed i would close entire FacebookDialog

Answer (score 0):

This will handle result without back press.
I have tried this and got success.

On Click (For Link Sample (You can modify your content)) :

```
 shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);
 ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
         .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
         .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")    
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                            .build();
                    shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

In onActivityResult method :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```